# How to convert cyrillic clipboard text to windows-1257 encoding

Tags: winapi, unicode, character-encoding, visual-foxpro, cyrillic

Visual FoxPro 9 grid control text field contains russian characters. Font charset is set to Cyrillic.

If russian text is pasted from web page to this field, ??? characters appear instead of russian letters.

I tried

```
CLEAR
_screen.FontCharSet= 204

cContents = STRCONV(_cliptext,9,1251,1)
?ccontents
cContents = STRCONV(_cliptext,6,1251,1)
?ccontents
cContents = STRCONV(cContents,9,1251,1)
?ccontents

FOR i=1 TO 15
  ?i,STRCONV(_cliptext,i)
  ENDFOR
```

But russian characters do not appear in any line.
For example, Аналитика produces output

[image]

How to convert russian clipboard data to windows 1251 encoding ?
Can some foxpro or windows API function used for this ?

**Update**

I tried code below from http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?function=-1&example=31 and copied  single english character to clipboard but it is not returned
Avaliable count of formats is 5. How to get raw clipboard content as unicode data ?

```
CLEAR
_screen.FontCharSet= 204

#DEFINE CF_TEXT              1
#DEFINE CF_BITMAP            2
#DEFINE CF_METAFILEPICT      3
#DEFINE CF_SYLK              4
#DEFINE CF_TIFF              6
#DEFINE CF_DIF               5
#DEFINE CF_OEMTEXT           7
#DEFINE CF_DIB               8
#DEFINE CF_PALETTE           9
#DEFINE CF_PENDATA          10
#DEFINE CF_RIFF             11
#DEFINE CF_WAVE             12
#DEFINE CF_UNICODETEXT      13
#DEFINE CF_ENHMETAFILE      14
#DEFINE CF_HDROP            15
#DEFINE CF_LOCALE           16
#DEFINE CF_DIBV5            17

DO declare
ncount=CountClipboardFormats()

? "Number of formats currently on the clipboard: ", ncount

cBuffer = Chr(CF_TEXT) + Repli(Chr(0),3) +;
    Chr(CF_OEMTEXT) + Repli(Chr(0),3) +;
    Chr(CF_UNICODETEXT) + Repli(Chr(0),3)

? "First available text format, ID: " +;
    LTRIM(STR(GetPriorityClipboardFormat(@cBuffer, 3)))
?'Buffer: ', cbuffer

PROCEDURE declare
    DECLARE INTEGER CountClipboardFormats IN user32

    DECLARE INTEGER GetPriorityClipboardFormat IN user32;
        STRING @paFormatPriorityList, INTEGER cFormats
 RETURN
```

Comment: In the Win32 API you can use `MultiByteToWideChar()` to convert Cyrillic to UTF-16, and then `WideCharToMultiByte()` to convert UTF-16 to Windows-1257

Comment: It looks like FoxPro _cliptext contains corrupted clipboard data. Is there API function which can read clipboard . Maybe `STRCONV(cText,5)` and others can used to convert it then instead of direct WinAPI

Comment: What raw data does `_cliptext` actually contain before you try to convert it? `_cliptext` is just a wrapper for `application.getClipboardString()`, but I can't find any information on how that interprets clipboard data when returning it as a string. I assume it reads the clipboard as `CF_TEXT` since FoxPro operates on 8bit strings. The clipboard can [synthesize various formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013.aspx#_win32_Synthesized_Clipboard_Formats) when needed, so that may be a contributing factor in your problem.

Comment: Outputs of _cliptext contents are shown in question. `strconv(..,15)` is hexbinary conversion which outputs 0x3F as shown in last line in image. FoxPro is not unicode application. So maybe _cliptext contains only question marks. Is it possible to call `getClipBoardString` or other WinAPI method directly to get unmodified clipboard content ?

Comment: `0x3F` is what happens when Unicode data is converted to Ansi using a codepage that does not support the Unicode characters being converted. See [Using Unicode in Visual FoxPro  Web and Desktop Applications](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxunicode/foxunicode.asp). As I said earlier, `_cliptext` is just a wrapper for `getClipboardString()`. If you want to access the clipboard data directly, use the Win32 API [`GetClipboardData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039.aspx) function.

Comment: I found working sample in http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?example=316&function=311 It returns cyrillic in foxpro. is it OK to use this ?